# How to transpile node_modules folder using just babel 7?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs

Trying to unit test reactjs application using mocha but getting error from es6 features (import/export) used inside `node_modules` folder. The application in question is transpiled using babel but since one of react component is using a module from `node_modules` its throwing error `Syntax Error:Unexpected token export`. I am aware that babel ignores node_modules folder by default, but not sure how to approach this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Test Command :-

```
  "test": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& mocha --require @babel/register --require ignore-styles -r jsdom-global/register \"./src/**/*.test.js\"",
```

babel.config.js :-

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  const presets = ["react-app"];
  const plugins = [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs", 
      "inline-react-svg"
  ];
  const ignore = [/node_modules/]
  api.cache(false); 
  return {
      presets, 
      plugins,
      ignore
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working!. Had to switch from **Mocha** to **Jest** since I was using **react-app-rewired** which was internally configured to use Jest. A small change in `config-override.js` was needed. Added a **jest** config with `"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!MODULES_TO_BE_TRANSPILED)"]`. Hope it helps others.

Comment: How could I transpile modules that start with /@ ? For example node_modules/@react-leaflet?

Answer (score 0):

try this command, you need to pass ignored directories in command line with `--ignored` option.

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel . -d ~/app_compressed/ --ignore node_modules,test,assets,stuff,views,public,test,spec,logs,lib/jasmine_examples,db,routes/api/drafts,**/drafts
```

Also, make sure to use a `babel.config.js` file instead of a `.babelrc` file.
so the config file will look like following.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        babelrcRoots: [
            '.',
            './modules/*'
        ],
    ignore: [/node_modules/],
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried --ignore option but no change. The tutorial shared is using babel-6 and I am using babel-7, so there are major changes to it isn't it?

Comment: Nope, not working either. I have updated question to show babel changes. Please check. Also I am facing error when trying to run mocha test command. Your answer suggests babel command. Can you please confirm? Please check my question for mocha test command being run.

Comment: well, it is confusing. I have updated my answer with my babel.config.js file and it is working.